# SQL Server Reporting Services shows DTD prohibited in XML document error

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting, service

I am getting the following error when running a reporting services report.

```
Process name: w3wp.exe
Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
Exception information: 
    Exception type: XmlException 
    Exception message: For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document.  To enable DTD processing set the ProhibitDtd property on XmlReaderSettings to false and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.
```

I select a report, enter the parameters(the parameters look messed up) and then press view report.  Then at the bottom the message "For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document.  To enable DTD processing set the ProhibitDtd property on XmlReaderSettings ..." shows up.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if your reporting server website has the correct local path folder.  You might need to do an iisreset if it is not correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct local path folder"?
The physical path to the Report Manager and Report Server seem to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the URL to download the xml file was actually enforcing the Form Authentication, so instead of getting the XML the reporting services was getting the ASP.NET / HTML login form.

To avoid half of a day of research, you should test your url in a fresh incognito browser in the first place, to make sure it works and you get the plain xml as intended.

Comment: That was my case too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this when using SSRS 2005 and running large reports containing XML data.

It would work when running say a monthly report, but give me this error when I ran a quarterly report.

Upgrading to SQL/SSRS 2008 fixed the issue for me!